# WiFi Repeater connect to router 100m away

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-extender

Here's the thing. I moved out from my apartment, to apartment in another building which is somewhere around 70m-100m away. I was thinking about buying WiFi repeater so I could keep using that network. What range should I go for? It wouldn't be a problem if my room faced my old apartment room. The thing is that my old apartment's room is on another side of that building. So WiFi signal must go through some walls. Can you suggest me some good repeaters for my case? Something under $50. The internet speed was 70mbps, so how much can I expect to have?

Comment: Realistically? None. For that budget there is no way you can even get a barely usable WiFi connection. Doing WiFi over longer (>50m) distances requires the use of directional or high end antennas on both ends and line of sight.

Comment: You can run Ethernet cable up to 100m :)